# pyzmq create a process with its own socket

Tags: python, zeromq, python-multithreading, pyzmq

I have some code thats monitoring some other changing files, what i would like to do is to start that code that uses zeromq with different socket, the way im doing it now seems to cause assertions to fail somewhere in libzmq, since i may be reusing the same socket. how do i ensure when i create a new process from the monitor class the context will not be reused?  thats what i think is going on, if you can tell there is some other stupidity on my part, please advise.
here is some code:

```
import zmq
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
from  zmq.eventloop.zmqstream  import ZMQStream
class Monitor(object):
    def __init(self)
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
        self.socket.connect("tcp//127.0.0.1:5055")
        self.stream =  ZMQStream(self._socket)
        self.stream.on_recv(self.somefunc)

    def initialize(self,id)
        self._id = id

    def somefunc(self, something)
        """work here and send back results if any """
        import json
        jdecoded = json.loads(something)
        if self_id == jdecoded['_id']
           """ good im the right monitor for you """
           work = jdecoded['message']
           results  = algorithm (work)
           self.socket.send(json.dumps(results))
        else:
           """let some other process deal with it, not mine """
           pass

 class Prefect(object):
    def __init(self, id)
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
        self.socket.bind("tcp//127.0.0.1:5055")
        self.stream =  ZMQStream(self._socket)
        self.stream.on_recv(self.check_if)
        self._id = id
        self.monitors = []
    def check_if(self,message):
        """find out from message's id whether we have
            started a proces for it previously"""
        import json
        jdecoded = json.loads(message)
        this_id = jdecoded['_id']
        if this_id in self.monitors:
            pass
        else:
            """start new process for it should have its won socket """
            new = Monitor()
            import Process
            newp = Process(target=new.initialize,args=(this_id) )
            newp.start()
            self.monitors.append(this_id) ## ensure its remembered
```

what is going on is that i want all the monitor processess and a single prefect process listening on the same port, so when prefect sees a request that it hasnt seen it starts a process for it, all the processes that exist probably should listen too but ignore messages not meant for them.
as it stands, if i do this i get some crash possibly related to concurrent access of the same zmq socket by something (i tried threading.thread, still crashes)  i read somewhere that concurrent access of a zmq socket by different threads is not possible. How would i ensure that new processes get their own zmq sockets?

EDIT:
the main deal in my app is that a request comes in via zmq socket, and a process(s) thats listening reacts to the message by:

```
1. If its directed at that process judged by the _id field, do some reading on a file and reply since one of the monitors match the messages _id, if none match, then:
2  If the messages _id files is not recognized, all monitors ignore it but the Prefect creates a process to handle that _id and all future messages to that id.
3. I want all the messages to be seen by the monitor processes as well as the prefect process, seems that seems easiest, 
4. All the messages are very small, avarage ~4096 bytes.   
5. The monitor does some non-blocking read and for each ioloop it sends what it has found out
```

more-edit=>and the prefect process binds now, and it will receive messages and echo them so they can be seen by monitors. This is what i have in mind, as the architecture but its not final.
    .

All the messages are arriving from remote users over a browser that lets the server know what a client wants  and the server sends the message to the backend via zmq(i did not show this, but is not hard)  so in production they might not bind/connect to localhost. 
I chose DEALER since it allows asyc / unlimited messages in either direction (see point 5.) and DEALER can bind with DEALER, and initial request/reply can arrive from  either side. The other that can do this is possibly DEALER/ROUTER.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the question. In your question, you said we can not use the same socket for the same process, but you did the opposite in the code as each time you create a monitor, you create it on the same socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you cannot keep using the same socket in a subprocess (multiprocessing usually uses fork to create subprocesses).  In general, what this means is that you don't want to create the socket that will be used in the subprocess until after the subprocess starts.
Since, in your case, the socket is an attribute on the Monitor object, you probably don't want to create the Monitor in the main process at all. That would look something like this:

```
def start_monitor(this_id):
    monitor = Monitor()
    monitor.initialize(this_id)
    # run the eventloop, or this will return immediately and destroy the monitor

... inside Prefect.check_if():

    proc = Process(target=start_monitor, args=(this_id,))
    proc.start()
    self.monitors.append(this_id)
```

rather than your example, where the only thing the subprocess does is assign an ID and then kill the process, ultimately having no effect.

Comment: right, let me give this a try and get back to you. nice idea this one.

Comment: +1 Good Answer. I'm new to zeromq but it's an awesome library :)

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean please by "a fork boundary"?=

Comment: Sorry, that means the subprocess created after forking (`os.fork()`), which is one of the ways multiprocessing creates subprocesses. You cannot continue to use zmq objects in the subprocess, even though the Python objects will still be available. The underlying FDs they use are not inherited.